# Is there any way to run JavaScript code in an isolated environment with dependencies, similar to Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-vm2

I've tried using the `isolated-vm` and `vm2` libraries to run code in an isolated environment, but I've run into issues where the required packages are not installed in the isolated environment.
`isolated-vm` not support module and `vm2` not installing it on isolated enviroment.

Here I tried with `vm2` to run script -

```
import { NodeVM, VMScript } from "vm2";
import { resolve } from "path";
import fs from "fs";

async function runScript(scriptPath, dependencies = []) {
  const scriptSource = fs.readFileSync(scriptPath, "utf8");

  const vm = new NodeVM({
    console: "inherit",
    sandbox: {},
    require: {
      external: true,
      import: dependencies,
    },
  });
  const script = new VMScript(scriptSource);
  const result = await vm.run(script);
  console.log(result);
}

runScript(resolve("./src/discordService.js"), ["discord.js-selfbot-v13"]);
```

Comment: Perhaps a container? But why cant just simple install the needed modules?

Comment: vm2 is deprecated. It has critical security issues and should not be used for production anymore. They suggest migrating to isolated-vm. 
Reference: https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2